# How do I make a basic c++ calculator calculate decimals

Tags: c++

I have a decent grasp with c++, and I made a basic calculator that can add, subtract, multiply, and divide. but I am having a hard time trying to get it to calculate decimals. Help please???

Comment: What you have done yet???

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: Are you just using int instead of float or double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ first.

You don't *calculate* decimals, you *display* a floating point number (often some `double`) with some decimals.

Use things like [std::showpoint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpoint) & [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) ...

If you want to show a *lot* of correct digits, you need to do [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) or BigNums. Then use a library, such as [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)